# create strings from 2d array of chars vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array of chars and i need to start at (0,0) and creat a string and check it against some value then still then add another char to the first one and check it. I need to do that in every dirction.   ex:

`array:

```
   B S W G E C Q
   W T W G E C Q
   D S W G E C Q
   Q W E G E C Q
   B S W H E C Q
   B S W G E O Q
   B S W G E C U`
```

value: first time B
next time BS
then bsw
then BSWGECQ
then BTWGEOU
then BW
and so on and so on

say im at the H their are like 8 way i need to check

any help in this vb.net problem would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you go the other direction and check your string, character by character, to see if that character is in the corresponding column in the array?

Comment: i want to be able to do other things to the strings i creat too not jsut check them for some value.

Comment: Then you'll probably want to go with some combination of recursive or nested loops.